# Role-based access control with Spring MVC 

Tags: authentication, spring-mvc, authorization

I would like to know the best practices for the role based access control with spring.

My requirements are,

I will have set of roles assigned to users say,

> **user1=admin,  user2=expert**

user1 will have the accesses write like

> /admin/member-management
>
> /admin/project-management

......

for user2....

> /myproject1/*

so if user2 tries to **access the url**

> /admin/member-management

will be redirect to authorization failure page.

Answer (score 6):

The standard framework to use with Spring MVC is [Spring Security](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security/). While it can be very complex, here's a minimal version of what you need: [4.2.2 A Minimal  Configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#ns-minimal)

In your case, the config would be something like this:

```
<http auto-config='true'>
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
</http>
```

Answer (score 4):

Spring Security has the concept of roles but out of the box it does not have a concept of permissions.   It does have a concept of [ACLs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html) but this ACLs are a lot more complicated than permissions, and they are tied to acting on specific objects, versus authorizing actions in general.

Take a look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/).  It has roles and [permissions](http://shiro.apache.org/permissions.html) that look very similar to what you gave as an example (using wildcards).   It is also [easy to use with Spring](http://shiro.apache.org/spring.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DashBoardController {

@Autowired
UserService userService;

private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DashBoardController.class);

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@RequestMapping(value = PathProxy.DashBoardUrls.SHOW_DASHBOARD, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String role(Locale locale, Model model) {
    String userRole = null;
    logger.info("dashboard Controller");
    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder
            .getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    for (SimpleGrantedAuthority simpleGrantedAuthority : authorities) {
        userRole = simpleGrantedAuthority.toString();
    }

    switch (userRole) {

    case "ROLE_ADMIN":

        return "dashboard/admin";

    case "ROLE_HR_MANAGER":

        return "dashboard/hr_manager";

    case "ROLE_MANAGER":

        return "dashboard/manager";

    case "ROLE_EMPLOYEE":

        return "dashboard/employee";

    case "ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN":

        return "dashboard/admin";

    default:

        break;
    }

    return userRole;

}
```

}