# Spring Security Implementation in Legacy Application

Tags: spring, spring-security

Let say I have a screen name ITEM thats performs different actions:

Save, Update, and Delete.

I have given a user ADMIN with a role of ADMIN and the ADMIN role can only perform SAVE and UPDATE operations on this screen. How can I customize this using spring security

Method Level Security checks only on roles but not one step further but that must pe possible with spring security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The very first thing you can do is hide / disable option URLs depending on role. So user with role other than ADMIN cant see/ click on SAVE and UPDATE.
2) Instead of writing method level code use interceptors, Intercept every request and check ROLE.
Check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7173910/role-based-access-control-with-spring-mvc) for more details.